# My Sql Entity Framework not supporting vs 2015

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ado.net-entity-data-model

> Im trying to connect My SQL Server to ASP.Net WEb api using DATA
>   Entity Models When im adding New  Db Entity Model This error Show in
>   The While Setup.

[image]

But I already Installed EF 6 There is Reference in Reference list

[image]

Im using

- Visual Studio 2015
- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- .NET Entity Framework 6.1.3
- MySql Data Entity 6.8.8
- MySql Data 8.011
- Web API / MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found Stable Solution with in a  few testing In This case im using Visual Studio 2015

1. Install My Sql Connector 6.9.11

   C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.11\Assemblies\v4.5
   [image]

   Go to My Sql Installation Location And Make sure got this Files!
2. Install  .Net Entity Framework 6.1.3  Using Nuget Manager
3. Rebuild Solution and Install My Sql Data 6.9.11
4. Rebuild Soulution and Install My SQl Entity Framework 6.9.11
5. Rebuild The Solution / Rebuild the Project
6. Now We Can Add New MySql Entity Model!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After Do this Some One get this error

> The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull

You Can Fix it using This Steps

1. Open MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client
2. Run this Commands In the console

   ```
    set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'; 
    set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'; 
    select @@optimizer_switch; 
    select @@GLOBAL.optimizer_switch;
   ```